# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-studio

### При запуске Активити: Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dzeon.brainapp.StartGame.onCreate(StartGame.java:26)
```

StartGame.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Locale;

import butterknife.BindView;
import mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton;

public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.buttonLockPlus1)
    FancyButton buttonLockPlus1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);
        
        buttonLockPlus1.setEnabled(false);
        
    }

    public void StartGameClick(View view){
        Log.i("Is Clickable", String.format(Locale.US, "nameView: %s, " +
                "isClickable: %s, isEnable %s", view.getTag(), view.isClickable(), view.isEnabled()));


            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

activity_start_game.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        tools:context=".StartGame">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                    android:tag="PlusBtn"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="StartGameClick"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="80sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
                    fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
                    fancy:fb_radius="20dp"
                    fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    fancy:fb_textFont="@string/oswald_medium_font">

                </mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton>

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                            android:tag="PlusBtnTime"
                            android:id="@+id/buttonTimer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:onClick="StartGameClick"
                            android:text="&#xf017;"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:fb_radius="10dp"
                            fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/fbutton_color_green_sea"
                            fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
                            fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
                            fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            fancy:fb_textFont="@string/font_awesome">

                        </mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton>
```

и т.д...

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StartGame"/>
    <activity android:name=".GameOverActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Немогу понять, что не так .
Через xml `android:enabled="false"` не работает, кнопка кликабельная.
Таже ситуация и с `android:clickable="false"`, и с `buttonLockPlus1.setClickable(false);`.
PS: Андроид только изучаю.

Comment: Она точно есть в разметке (кнопка с id `buttonLockPlus1`)?

Comment: Да,  есть. Только что убрал `@BindView(R.id.buttonLockPlus1)` и добавил в метод `onCreate()`   `buttonLockPlus1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLockPlus1);` и все заработало.

Comment: С ButterKnife надо делать вызов `ButterKnife.bind(this);` после `setContentView` и до обращения к виджетам.

Comment: Увидел в оф. доках. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена. Все дело в невнимательности.
В метод `onCreate()` под `setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_game);` нужно было добавить `ButterKnife.bind(this);`.